# tvOS not loading external TVML file

Tags: javascript, url, tvos, tvml

While creating a new Client-Server tvOS App, tvOS will not get the data from my external `tvml` file.  This is the Error: `ITML <Error>: Failed to load launch URL with error: (null)`

This is the `main.js` code

```
function getDocument(url) {
    var templateXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    templateXHR.responseType = "document";
    templateXHR.addEventListener("load", function() {pushDoc(templateXHR.responseXML);}, false);
    templateXHR.open("GET", url, true);
    templateXHR.send();
    return templateXHR;
}

function pushDoc(document) {
    navigationDocument.pushDocument(document);
}

App.onLaunch = function(options) {
    var templateURL = 'niclasblog.com/appletv/main.tvml';
    getDocument(templateURL);
}

App.onExit = function() {
    console.log('App finished');
}
```

And I have attached the `main.tvml` file as well

```
<document>
   <alertTemplate>
      <title>Test</title>
      <description>This is a test</description>
      <button>
         <text>Yes</text>
      </button>
      <button>
         <text>No</text>
      </button>
   </alertTemplate>
</document>
```

That code is directly from the Apple Documentation, so I do not know why it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App.onLaunch function you could get the BASEURL and use this for loading all your assets:

```
App.onLaunch = function(options) {
  var BASEURL = options.BASEURL;
  // etc.
}
```

You can also consider a different approach to loading templates. Consider using a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse an XML String. This way you can write Multiline template strings with "real" content e.g.

```
getDocument(options) {
let parser = new DOMParser();
let templateString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <document>
       <alertTemplate>
          <description>${options.translate.errorRandomErrorAlertText}</description>
          <button>
             <text>${options.translate.utilOk}/text>
          </button>
       </alertTemplate>
    </document>`;
return parser.parseFromString(templateString, "application/xml");
}
```

I've written a [generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-appletvjs) for specfically for Apple TVML apps using es6, its still early in its development, but might help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this

```
var templateURL = 'niclasblog.com/appletv/main.tvml';
```

with fully qualified URI

```
var templateURL = 'https://niclasblog.com/appletv/main.tvml';
```

Also

```
templateXHR.responseType = "document";
```

is not needed as that seem to be the default behavior.